# Using Variables in Declared in Different File on Unix Script

Tags: unix, variables

How can I keep variables used in a script in a secondary file? For example, use store variables in `myscript.env` for use in a script `myscript.sh`.

So whenever I need to change variables I can edit `myscript.env` instead of `myscript.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply include the file using the "dot operator".

assuming these two files are in the same directory, the following will work:

t.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

# Note the first dot on the following line
. ./t.env 
echo $TESTVAR
```

t.env:

```
TESTVAR="Hello world"
```

When run:

```
~/tmp$ sh ./t.sh
Hello world
```

Comment: Thank you Carl! --- I've been missing the ". ./"  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a usual design pattern. Think along the lines of

**myscript.sh:**

```
#!/path/to/shell

CONFIG_FILE=myscript.env
CONFIG_DIR=`dirname $0`
# or e.g. CONFIG_DIR=/etc/myscript

CONFIG="$CONFIG_DIR/$CONFIG_FILE"
. $CONFIG

echo "SOMEVAR=$SOMEVAR"
```

**myscript.env**

```
SOMEVAR="The value of some var"
```

Now `/path/to/myscript.sh` will output `SOMEVAR=The value of some var`